# Storing Db in asset folder or create via code

Tags: android

In my android projects I need database to store data for offline usage.

For that I am looking at two options 1)Creating the empty db and copying it to asset 2)Creating the db via code

which option will be good as my app is handling secure data.
weather it will cause any security vulnerability if we store the db structure in asset folder as it will be easily available if we  extract .apk file.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

If your database has something you don't want your legitimate user to see, look for a new project because you cannot attain that. Using a static database in the APK is as you know, easily viewable, but creating it from your app also leaves something that is viewable. You could encrypt the contents, but then you have the problem of how you store the key in a way the user cannot access -- so you really haven't solved anything.

Back to your original question though -- is the data static, or is your application ever going to make changes to it? If the data is static, providing a pre-populated database is fine. If the application is intended to be able to make changes though, you are much better served by letting the application create and manage updates on the database, its schema, and its contents. Following Google's examples will get you there.

Comment: Thaks ..Data is dynamic ie app will change it frequently whenever its online.I can encrypt data but i need to hide the db structure also .then which will be the ideal way .My aim is to make app the app as secure as possible

Comment: If what you're protecting is interesting enough, you're fighting an uphill battle, particularly since this is an Android application (which is easily reverse engineered using commonly available tools). If I were in your place, I would consider a combination of sqlite and a proprietary binary file; I would use sqlite to store data helping me to locate what is in the binary file but not something that needs to be secure (assuming I needed that flexibility). I would also write my code using the NDK to make reverse engineering a little more difficult.